# How to create api using post request with json as payload using swagger

Tags: java, api, swagger

I try to create api for post request using swagger but cannot determine what parameters I should configure in swagger in order to create this API.

I used postman in order to get all information about the response and implement in swagger.

```
'/api/v1/labels':
post:
      tags:
        - devices
      summary: 'create new label'
      description: 'create new label to a given device'
      operationId: createNewLabel
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: x-access-token
          description: 'cognito token'
          in: header
          type: string
          required: true
        - in: body
          name: body
          description: add label details
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/labelRequest'
      responses:
        '201':
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/labelRequest'
          description: Created
```

and this is the definition I wrote:

```
labelRequest:
    type: object
    items:
      $ref: '#/definitions/labelRequestBody'

  labelRequestBody:
    type: object
    properties:
      device_ids:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
          example: ["9bc11e25-4db2-4780-b761-390e3806082a"]
          format: uuid
      name:
        type: string
        example: new_label
```

This is the API call:

https:///api/v1/labels

with those headers:

x-access-token

and with this body as payload:

```
{
    "device_ids":["ea4b9daa-07cd-4cd6-981f-c86e1e81f04c"],
    "name":"labelName"
}
```

expected result is: 201 (created)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, just change the `labelRequest` schema to:

```yaml
definitions:
  labelRequest:
    type: object
    properties:
      device_ids:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
          # Array item example should NOT be enclosed in []
          example: "9bc11e25-4db2-4780-b761-390e3806082a"
          format: uuid
      name:
        type: string
        example: new_label
```